# Устанавливается sdl2 а потом cmd пишет что он не установлен

Tags: python, windows

У меня есть приложение на python kivy, оно не запускается, пишет 
**sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.**
решил я значит установить sdl2 (который у меня всегда был установлен),
командой **pip3 install kivy.deps.sdl2**, cmd пишет что все установилось, но потом при попытке удалить, пишется что у меня нет sdl2 который только что был установлен. Как это возможно?[image: ошибка в cmd]

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте переменные среды на Windows. Если у вас несколько пакетов Python установлено в системе, то по умолчанию всё равно будет работать только прописанный в переменной `PATH`.
И на всякий случай в командной строке проверьте версию Python `python -V` и установленные модули `pip freeze`.